# Onmouseout not triggering event following 'paste'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm running a form which contains a textbox for the entry of a PIN code.

When typing the code in, each character is replaced with an * and the actual value entered is put into a new variable.
Click 'Submit' or 'Enter' and it works fine. (code below).

However, when I paste the code into the textbox, (id=user_pin_code) the characters are not replaced with * and the values are not entered to that other variable (PINcode), which means that, when I click 'Submit' or hit Enter key, the value is not passed to the next script.

It seems I need the `onmouseup` or `onmouseout` event to trigger the JS (to change the chars to ****** and to put the actual characters into 'PINcode' ) but, those two events don't seem to work which means the new variable is not populated.

Any guidance or pointers would be much appreciated.

```
<script>

\$(document).ready(function(e) {

var actualTextEntered = ""; 


    \$("#user_pin_code").keyup(function(e) {
    
                   
        var x = document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value;
        
        
        actualTextEntered += x.replace(/\\*/g,"");
        //actualTextEntered += x.replace(/*/g,"");          
        
        addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
            
            //console.log( 'key =   ' + key );      
            if ( key === "Backspace" ) {
                // Do something
                actualTextEntered = ''; 
                x='';
            }
            
            if ( key === "Return" ) {
            //console.log( 'key pressed = '  + key);
            }
        });
        
        
        
        document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value = "";
        
        for (var i=0;i<actualTextEntered.length;i++)
        {   
        document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value += "*";
        document.getElementById("PINcode").value = actualTextEntered;
        }   
        
        
    });

});

</script>);
```

Comment: Ooo, where I have used keyup in the script, I tried 'mouseout' instead of 'onmouseout' and it seems to work. That was a guess. Why are some events  prefixed with 'on' and others not?

Comment: `<input type='password'>` gives you this behavior for free.

Comment: You are using jquery and in jquery it is 'mouseout' not 'onmouseout'. onmouseout is for when you are only using javascript without jquery and you also have to use it like this: `element.onmouseout = function(e)`

Comment: Thank you both. Long time from when I wrote that code and forgot it used jQuery. :(  James, input type='password' is used to enter the password. this is the second stage, of two, where 'password' isn't suitable here.  Once a user has entered u/name and pwd, they may save it to browser. Then they enter their PIN and I don't want it to be saved at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code if it works:

```
<script>

\$(document).ready(function(e) {

var actualTextEntered = ""; 


    \$("#user_pin_code").keyup(function(e) {
    
                   
        var x = document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value;
        
        
        actualTextEntered += x.replace(/\\*/g,"");
        //actualTextEntered += x.replace(/*/g,"");          
        
        \$("#user_pin_code").keydown(function(event) {
            const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
            
            //console.log( 'key =   ' + key );      
            if ( key === "Backspace" ) {
                // Do something
                actualTextEntered = ''; 
                x='';
            }
            
            if ( key === "Return" ) {
            //console.log( 'key pressed = '  + key);
            }
        });
        
        
        
        document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value = "";
        
        for (var i=0;i<actualTextEntered.length;i++)
        {   
        document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value += "*";
        document.getElementById("PINcode").value = actualTextEntered;
        }   
        
        
    });

});

</script>);
```

Comment: Genuine Q.  Is that one function inside another - keydown inside a keyup? Should they be separate/independent? (I'm no JS whizz. perl/php is my thing).

Comment: Yes. You should use both the keyup and keydown functions separately.